# How should this multinomial identity be written?

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, symmetric-functions

**Question** if it is correct, how is the identity tagged (4) below usually written, and can the use of conjugate partitions be avoided?

**Motivation** I apologize for the length of this question - it's as concise as i can make it - but i've been scribbling on this for a couple of days, and, as someone working alone,  would appreciate help in finding errors of logic, deficiencies in terminology etc. my target is to try to prove the theorem that the sum and product of algebraic numbers are algebraic, via the construction of equations with these roots. my present path towards this requires showing that any symmetric polynomial in the roots of an equation can be expressed in terms of the set of polynomials which are symmetric sums of powers of the roots. i think i see a way forward here, but have been hampered by limitations in my notation.  thinking about how to multiply symmetric polynomials seems to lead me quite quickly to consideration of some facts about partitions. the specific question here is an offshoot.

**Partitions** for some purposes it seems useful to view partitions as a subset of the set of maps $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Let $F$ be the subset of maps $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which have *finite support*, and let $P \subset F$ be the subset of $F$ consisting of maps which are non-increasing. then $P$ is in 1-1 correspondence with the set of partitions. we will indicate a partition by the lower-case Greek letter $\sigma$ and reserve $\tau$ for an arbitrary element of $F$. it will be convenient sometimes to use the abbreviation $\sigma_j$ for $\sigma(j)$. the informal concept of a *part* of $\tau$ means any non-zero element of the image considered as a multi-set

the weight of any element $\tau \in F$ is the sum of its parts:
$$
|\tau| = \sum_i \tau_i
$$
and for such a function its *height* is the size of the largest part(s). for a partition no part is larger than the first, so its height may be denoted by $\sigma_0$

the support of a partition $\sigma$ is naturally encoded as a finite ordinal $n_{\sigma}$ where
$$
n_\sigma = \min\{k \in \mathbb{N}:\sigma(k)=0\}
$$
so we have $n_\sigma=|\{k \in \mathbb{N}:\sigma(k) \gt 0\}|$ and $\sigma(n_\sigma)=0$.

for all non-trival partitions $n_\sigma  \gt 0$ and $\sigma(n_\sigma - 1) \gt 0 $

**$\chi$-functions** define $\chi \in (\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$ (with  $k \mapsto \chi_k$) by setting $\chi_k(j)=1$ if $j \gt k$ and $\chi_k(j)=0$ if $j \le k$

**The ^-transform** for any function $\tau$ we may define a partition $\hat \tau$ by the transform
$$
\hat \tau (j) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} \chi_j \tau(i) \tag{1}
$$
if $\tau \in P$ then $\hat \tau$ is the conjugate of $\tau$.

conjugacy for partitions is expressed by the relations
$$
\chi_j \sigma_k = \chi_k \hat\sigma_j \tag{2}
$$
so that

$$
\hat{ \hat \sigma}(k) = \sum_j \chi_k \hat \sigma(j) =\sum_j \chi_j \sigma(k) = \sigma(k)
$$
the function $\partial:P \to F$ is defined by 
$$
\partial \sigma(j) = \sigma(j) - \sigma(j+1)
$$
for any $\tau \in F$ we may define the multinomial coefficient
$$
M(\tau) = \frac{(\sum_i \tau_i)!}{\prod_i \tau_i!} \tag{3}
$$
also we may write $\tau! = \prod_i \tau_i!$, thus (3) may be expressed more trimly as:
$$
M(\tau) = \frac{|\tau|!}{\tau!}
$$

let $P_m$ denote the subset of partitions with weight $m$, and $Q_n$ represent the subset of partitions $\sigma$ for which $\sigma(n)=0$.

then, by setting all variables to 1 in the expansion of $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^m$ we have the identity
$$
\sum_{\sigma \in P_m \cap Q_n} M(\sigma) \binom{n}{n_\sigma} \frac{n_\sigma !}{\partial \hat \sigma !} = n^m \tag{4}
$$
a simple example with $m=3, n=4$:

$$
\sigma=[3], n_\sigma=1, \partial \hat \sigma = \partial[1,1,1] =[0,0,1], \partial \hat \sigma!=1, M(\sigma) = \frac{3!}{3!}=1, \binom{n}{n_\sigma}=4
$$
term adds 4 
$$
\sigma=[2,1], n_\sigma=2, \partial \hat \sigma = \partial[2,1] =[1,1], \partial \hat \sigma!=1, M(\sigma) = \frac{3!}{2!1!}=3, \binom{n}{n_\sigma}=6
$$
term adds $3 \times 6 \times 2 = 36$
$$
\sigma=[1,1,1], n_\sigma=3, \partial \hat \sigma = \partial[3] =[3], \partial \hat \sigma!=3!=6, M(\sigma) = \frac{3!}{1!1!1!}=6, \binom{n}{n_\sigma}=4
$$
term adds $6 \times 4 \times \frac{3!}{3!} =24$

so the total for the three partitions is $4+36+24=4^3$.